# AutoMapper mapping the first item in an array and other properties

Tags: mapping, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have an object thus:

```
public class TopLevel{
  public string AProperty {get;set;}
  public int AnotherProperty {get;set;}
  public SecondLevel[] SecondLevels {get;set;}
}

public class SecondLevel{
  public string AThing {get;set;}
  public int AnotherThing {get;set;}
}
```

this I want to map to this:

```
public class JoinedClass{
  public string AProperty {get;set;}
  public int AnotherProperty {get;set;}
  public string Athing {get;set;}
  public string AnotherThing {get;set;}
}
```

using the FirstOrDefault member of the SecondLevels array.
I presume this is possible, but cant seem to work out how to do it.

I have tried...

```
CreateMap<TopLevel, JoinedClass>()
  .ForAllMembers(opt=>opt.MapFrom(tl=>tl.SecondLevels.FirstOrDefault())
  .ForMemeber(jc=>jc.AProperty, opt=>opt.MapFrom(tl=>tl.AProperty)
  .ForMemeber(jc=>jc.AnotherProperty , opt=>opt.MapFrom(tl=>tl.AnotherProperty );
```

but that doesn't seem to map any properties at all. I have also put the `ForAllMembers()` last in the above mapping, with no luck either.
I am using AutoMapper 6.2.0

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work", and what error you have?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use **ForAllMembers** you can always map one for one, here is an example

**Setup Mapping Config**

```
public static MapperConfiguration SetupMapping()
{
    return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        cfg.CreateMap<TopLevel, JoinedClass>()
            .ForMember(jc => jc.Athing, opt => opt.MapFrom(t1 => t1.SecondLevels.FirstOrDefault().AThing))
            .ForMember(jc => jc.AnotherThing, opt => opt.MapFrom(t1 => t1.SecondLevels.FirstOrDefault().AnotherThing))
            ;
    });
}
```

**Example**

```
var seconds = new SecondLevel[] {
new SecondLevel { AThing = "one", AnotherThing = 1 },
new SecondLevel { AThing = "two", AnotherThing = 2 }
        };

var toplevel = new TopLevel { AProperty = "top", AnotherProperty = 99, SecondLevels = seconds };

MapperConfiguration config = SetupMapping();
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var result = mapper.Map<JoinedClass>(toplevel);
```